# Jquery - Pseudo-recursive function with "this" element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to apply a cool animation effect on a list with Jquery using a pseudo-recursive function.

It works pretty well for the first item, but after the first loop, the `this` which was selecting  `#column-left section` becomes the `li` so of course, the function does not find the next `li:hidden` because it is already inside. Is there a way for me to come back to my original `this` once the "this" has changed or maybe do something different ?

```
$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function fadeItem(){
console.log(this);
$(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(fadeItem);
});
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Why don't you wrap it all in a function and use that?

Comment: You could simply rewrite your function using the call method to pass "this" to each iteration: `$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function fadeItem(){
    $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn.call(this, fadeItem);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I found an even better way:

```
$(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(100).show("fast",function(){
    $(this).next(':hidden').show("fast",arguments.callee);  
});
```

Simply use `next()` ([more info](http://api.jquery.com/next/)) to select the next li then call the function itselt using `arguments.callee` ([more info](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/JavaScript/0140__Function/arguments.htm))

Which gives the full following script below to show the list and hide it:

```
//show
$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(100).show("fast",function(){
         $(this).next().show("fast",arguments.callee);  
    });
});

//hide
$("#column-left section").mouseleave(function(){
     $(this).find('ul li:visible:last').delay(100).hide("fast",function(){
          $(this).prev().hide("fast",arguments.callee); 
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about after the `.fadeIn()` trigger a `mouseenter` event on the parent `section` element:

```
$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        //check to make sure there are more hidden `<li>` elements
        if ($this.siblings('li:hidden').length > 0) {

            //trigger a `mouseenter` event on the parent `section` element to continue the queue
            $this.parents('section').trigger('mouseenter');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bhTnL/2/

Comment: This doesn't even make sense.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, I found a more simple way to do it but I definitly used your method :
`$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function(){
     $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn("slow",function(){
   $(this).parents('section').trigger('mouseenter'); 
  });
 });`

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, your method is the best so far, could you explain me the difference between "this" and the variable $this, why create a variable and not use "this" directly instead ? I tried it it does not work, but I wonder why.

Comment: @user1095066 Within the `.fadeIn()` function, `this` refers to the DOM element that is fading in (the hidden `<li>` element). To use jQuery functions on `this` you have to wrap it in `$(this)`, and since we want to run several jQuery functions at different times, it behooves us to cache the selector so we don't have to create a jQuery object each time we want to reference `this`. Long-story-short: caching `$(this)` in the `$this` variable improves performance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.end()`:

```
$(this)
    .find('ul li:hidden:first')
    .delay(500)
    .fadeIn(fadeItem)
    .end(); // returns to first selector
```

But you don't actually need to do this. To select the next hidden `li`, just do this:

```
$(this)
    .find('ul li:hidden:first')
        .delay(500)
        .fadeIn(fadeItem)
    .closest("li:hidden")
        .delay(500)
        .fadeIn(fadeItem);
```

Comment: Your solution is not clear to me, where is the function located ?

Answer (score 0):

Every function has access to the `call` method which allows you to pass in your `this` parameter. I rewrote your original solution using it here:

```
$("#column-left section").mouseenter(function fadeItem(){
    $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn.call(this, fadeItem);
});
```

Comment: $(this).find('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn("slow", fadeItem.call(this,a));

That would be the good code for your solution but it does not work, it just make an infinite loop without stopping and does not even show the list elements.